# IndentationError: unexpected indent with web.py

Tags: python, web.py

I have this code in app.py file

```
import web

urls = (
  '/hello', 'Index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/')

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.hello_form()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(name="Nobody", greet="Hello")
        greeting = "%s" % (form.menu)
        if greeting == "ct":
            return render.ct(greeting=greeting)
        elif greeting == "vjc":
            return render.vjc(greeting=greeting)
        elif greeting == "sa":
            return render.sa(greeting=greeting)
        elif greeting == "wc":
            return render.wc(greeting=greeting)
        elif greeting == "pt":
            return render.pt(greeting=greeting)
        else:
            return render.s(greeting=greeting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and when I start the server in cmd, I get following unexpected indent error

```
$ python bin/app.py
  File "bin/app.py", line 18
    if greeting == "ct":
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Can anyone tell me the reason of this error. I think I have checked the indentation multiple times and I don't see any problem with the code.

Thank for all the help in advance!

Comment: Have you double-checked your whitespace (tabs vs. spaces)?

Comment: thank you.. I was mixing tabs and spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing tabs and spaces for indentation. The `if` line uses tabs, but the preceding line only spaces:

```
>>> lines = '''\
...         greeting = "%s" % (form.menu)
...                 if greeting == "ct":
... '''
>>> lines
'        greeting = "%s" % (form.menu)\n\t\tif greeting == "ct":\n'
>>> # ^^^ is all spaces, while here     ^^^^ you use two tabs.  
...
```

Python expands tabs to every 8th column, but you probably have your editor set to using only 4 spaces for a tab, further increasing the confusion. Your `greeting` line is indented to 8 spaces, while the two tabs on the next line are expanded to *16* spaces.

Don't ever use a mix indentation styles; stick to either only tabs or only spaces.

You can configure most editors to use spaces *only* for indentation; this is what the [Python styleguide (PEP 8)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends:

> ### Tabs or Spaces?
>
> Never mix tabs and spaces.
>
> The most popular way of indenting Python is with spaces only. The second-most popular way is with tabs only. Code indented with a mixture of tabs and spaces should be converted to using spaces exclusively. When invoking the Python command line interpreter with the -t option, it issues warnings about code that illegally mixes tabs and spaces. When using -tt these warnings become errors. These options are highly recommended!
>
> For new projects, spaces-only are strongly recommended over tabs. Most editors have features that make this easy to do.